# Custom MVC AuthorizeAttribute for ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement a custom authorization attribute on my Web API controllers, but came across an unexpected behavior.

```
     <Authorize(Users:="myUser")>
     Public Function GetTodoItems() As IQueryable(Of TodoItem)
```

The above code works very well: It will allow *"myUser"* to retrieve the items, bot nobody else is allowed access. However, when I try the same approach with my custom authorization, the entire check is skipped, and any user can access the resource. Neither the `AuthorizeCore` nor the `OnAuthorization` overridden methods in my derived class are called.

```
     <MyAuth(Users:="myUser")>
     Public Function GetTodoItems() As IQueryable(Of TodoItem)
```

The derived class inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`, and the project is deployed on IIS, with *Windows Authentication* & *Impersonation enabled*, and *Anonymous Authentication* disabled.

If I add the same custom authorization to an MVC Controller, then it works. But on the API Controllers, nothing. If the `Authorize` attribute wouldn't have worked either, it would have made more sense. Am I missing something? Is this an expected behavior, or a bug in the Beta?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` from System.Web.Http.dll for Web API instead of `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`.

That is, because `namespace System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` is derived from `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`. The filters are handled automatically by the Web API. In my own implementation I derived directly from `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` for handling of the basic HTTP authentication.

Comment: Thanks, changing the namespace worked! It still seems weird that using the `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` worked for the Web API, whilst my class, which derived from that exact class, did not.

Comment: It seems like many types duplicate between MVC and Web API. Maybe they will be merged and we will have single sample of type in the release. So maybe either of the `AuthorizeAttibute` objects are being checked internally, just a guess.

Answer (score 4):

I've built my own custom implementation for Basic Authorization:

http://remy.supertext.ch/2012/04/basic-http-authorization-for-web-api-in-mvc-4-beta/

Maybe this helps.