# How to secure an ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I want to build a **RESTful** web service using ASP.NET Web API that third-party developers will use to access my application's data.

I've read quite a lot about **OAuth** and it seems to be the standard, but finding a good sample with documentation explaining how it works (and that actually does work!) seems to be incredibly difficult (especially for a newbie to OAuth).

Is there a sample that actually builds and works and shows how to implement this?

I've downloaded numerous samples:

- DotNetOAuth - documentation is hopeless from a newbie perspective
- Thinktecture - can't get it to build

I've also looked at blogs suggesting a simple token-based scheme (like [this](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/)) - this seems like re-inventing the wheel but it does have the advantage of being conceptually fairly simple.

It seems there are many questions like this on SO but no good answers.

What is everybody doing in this space?

Answer (score 300):

**Update:**

I have added this link to my other answer [how to use JWT authentication for ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api/) here for anyone interested in JWT.

---

We have managed to apply HMAC authentication to secure Web API, and it worked okay. HMAC authentication uses a secret key for each consumer which both consumer and server both know to hmac hash a message, HMAC256 should be used. Most of the cases, hashed password of the consumer is used as a secret key.

The message normally is built from data in the HTTP request, or even customized data which is added to HTTP header, the message might include:

1. Timestamp: time that request is sent (UTC or GMT)
2. HTTP verb: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.
3. post data and query string,
4. URL

Under the hood, HMAC authentication would be:

Consumer sends a HTTP request to web server, after building the signature (output of hmac hash), the template of HTTP request:

```
User-Agent: {agent}   
Host: {host}   
Timestamp: {timestamp}
Authentication: {username}:{signature}
```

Example for GET request:

```
GET /webapi.hmac/api/values

User-Agent: Fiddler    
Host: localhost    
Timestamp: Thursday, August 02, 2012 3:30:32 PM 
Authentication: cuongle:LohrhqqoDy6PhLrHAXi7dUVACyJZilQtlDzNbLqzXlw=
```

The message to hash to get signature:

```
GET\n
Thursday, August 02, 2012 3:30:32 PM\n
/webapi.hmac/api/values\n
```

Example for POST request with query string (signature below is not correct, just an example)

```
POST /webapi.hmac/api/values?key2=value2

User-Agent: Fiddler    
Host: localhost    
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Timestamp: Thursday, August 02, 2012 3:30:32 PM 
Authentication: cuongle:LohrhqqoDy6PhLrHAXi7dUVACyJZilQtlDzNbLqzXlw=

key1=value1&key3=value3
```

The message to hash to get signature

```
GET\n
Thursday, August 02, 2012 3:30:32 PM\n
/webapi.hmac/api/values\n
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

Please note that form data and query string should be in order, so the code on the server get query string and form data to build the correct message.

When HTTP request comes to the server, an authentication action filter is implemented to parse the request to get information: HTTP verb, timestamp, uri, form data and query string, then based on these to build signature (use hmac hash) with the secret key (hashed password) on the server.

The secret key is got from the database with the username on the request.

Then server code compares the signature on the request with the signature built; if equal, authentication is passed, otherwise, it failed.

The code to build signature:

```
private static string ComputeHash(string hashedPassword, string message)
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashedPassword.ToUpper());
    string hashString;

    using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
    {
        var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    return hashString;
}
```

So, how to prevent replay attack?

Add constraint for the timestamp, something like:

```
servertime - X minutes|seconds  <= timestamp <= servertime + X minutes|seconds
```

(servertime: time of request coming to server)

And, cache the signature of the request in memory (use MemoryCache, should keep in the limit of time). If the next request comes with the same signature with the previous request, it will be rejected.

The demo code is put as here:
https://github.com/cuongle/Hmac.WebApi

Comment: Thanks, that's useful code to look at. Did you have some client code too?

Comment: You can use filter for testing or write a HttpClient to create request.

Comment: @CuongLe In your `AuthenticateAttribute` on GitHub you are validating the timestamp *AND* checking if the previous signature was in the memory cache for preventing replay attacks. Is it necessary for both checks to happen? Wouldn't it be more reliable to just check the timestamp manually (your first suggestion)?

Comment: @James: only timestamp seems not sufficient much, during short of time they may simulate the request and sent to server, I have just edited my post, use both would be the best.

Comment: @CuongLe Using the user's hashed password as a secret key to sign requests is a good idea. At least you will make sure that the secret key remains secret and will never be transmitted over the wire. However, hashing the password needs a salt, and normally that salt should be random. In your case, this salt should be the same in both the client and the server. Also, it means that all users' passwords are hashed using the same salt. Isn't that bad? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is working as it should? you are hashing the timestamp with the message and caching that message. This would mean a different signature each request which would render your cached signature useless.

Comment: @FilipStas: seems I don't get your point, the reason to use Cache in here is to prevent relay attack, nothing more

Comment: Please explain how to add authenticated user and make to allow AllowAnonymous attribute is working, currently it is not working.

Comment: Great answer. Could you show how a user could generate their signature? I'm stuck at this part.

Comment: @ChrisO: You can refer [this page] (http://jokecamp.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/). I will update this source soon

Comment: @CuongLe How does the consumer get the secret? In your post you state that the hashed password is typically what is used but how would that work where the password is salted and hashed then stored in a database? Surely the consumer can't just requested the password? What am I missing here?

Comment: @nwdev: It's like how you get the password on website, by registering or sending over the email

Comment: @CuongLe Do you use this to authenticate the app using your API, or authenticate a real user?

Comment: @Bargitta: What is the point in your question?

Comment: @CuongLe I have posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630447/can-i-use-http-basic-authentication-to-authentic-both-the-apps-and-users-in-web

Comment: I really like this solution, however how do you prevent an attacker from prying into the client source and retrieving the private key in order to use this to build the signature ??

Comment: I don't know if I understood this ok. So, when you are consuming that API, you need to put something in QueryString like following url : http://localhost/webapi.hmac/api/values?username="asdasda"&key="asdasd" ? You parse that query string in OnActionExecuting and set specific headers?

Comment: @Kosmo The values (userName:signature) are added to the Authorization header

Comment: @CuongLe Hi Cuong, so in the context of an MVC web application, after users have logged in (authenticated), did you send back the hashed password as an hidden field in the form? Or how can you get the secret key to sign the message on the client side?

Comment: @kooldave98: Good question, I guess we don't hardcode the password in javascript file, instead it should be retrieved from database. Also, js files should be minified.

Comment: @Kosmo: It puts on HTTP request header

Comment: @ToanNguyen: seems I am not sure I completely understand your question, if your application is ASP.NET MVC you should use built-in form authentication. You can store secret key (password) for each user in database

Comment: @CuongLe My question was how can you calculate the based64 value on the client side so that you would be able to compare that value with the one from the server, since you need the secret key, in this case it is the hash value of a user's password? So I guess when you rendered the page, you included the hash value into a hidden field?

Comment: @ToanNguyen: on Javascript, you can use cryptojs at: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ to calculate hash. Hidden field will store value on body of request, not the header. In this case, you should call api by ajax instead letting the form submits directly to server

Comment: @CuongLe So it means you have to push the "secret" in the form you render from the server. Which means that a malicious user will be able to get it to conduct the signature of the message? How do you ensure that data is not submitted by a malicious user?

Comment: @ToanNguyen that is exactly what I need to know too. I still cannot understand how to prevent an attacker from getting the secret !!!

Comment: @CuongLe: okay, after retrieving the secret from the database, how can you then prevent an attacker from getting this retrieved secret ??

Comment: @ToanNguyen: well I now understand what you both meant, your questions are for HMAC authentication in general, not specific for ASP.NET Web API, so in the context of client side, we need to trust user. You can put the secret key anywhere that "anonymous" user cannot access, Js files, or even on html page as long as the secret key is NOT brought over by HTTP request. If you put secret key on the form only for authenticated user, how can malicious user access that form?

Comment: @kooldave98: please see my previous comment

Comment: My simple approach would be to pass User ID/PWD in the custome HTTP request header and to implement HTTPS/SSL for the WEB API

Comment: The solution suggested works , but you can't prevent  Man-in-the-Middle attack , for that you have to implement HTTPS

Comment: Is this an implementation of OAuth?

Comment: @CuongLe what about csrf and xss attack in your apporach,a hidden secret in form will not prevent these attacks?

Comment: @cuongle how to use this solution without authentication? there is 2 notes: 1. what would be alternative to _password_? 2. in one of your comments, you wrote _If you put secret key on the form only for authenticated user, how can malicious user access that form_, without authentication what is the answer to that question?

Answer (score 34):

I would suggest starting with the most straightforward solutions first - maybe simple HTTP Basic Authentication + HTTPS is enough in your scenario.

If not (for example you cannot use https, or need more complex key management), you may have a look at HMAC-based solutions as suggested by others. A good example of such API would be Amazon S3 (http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html)

I wrote a blog post about HMAC based authentication in ASP.NET Web API. It discusses both Web API service and Web API client and the code is available on bitbucket. http://www.piotrwalat.net/hmac-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api/

Here is a post about Basic Authentication in Web API: http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-message-handlers/

Remember that if you are going to provide an API to 3rd parties, you will also most likely be responsible for delivering client libraries. Basic authentication has a significant advantage here as it is supported on most programming platforms out of the box. HMAC, on the other hand, is not that standardized and will require custom implementation. These should be relatively straightforward but still require work.

PS. There is also an option to use HTTPS + certificates. http://www.piotrwalat.net/client-certificate-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-windows-store-apps/

Answer (score 23):

Have you tried DevDefined.OAuth?

I have used it to secure my WebApi with 2-Legged OAuth. I have also successfully tested it with PHP clients.

It's quite easy to add support for OAuth using this library. Here's how you can implement the provider for ASP.NET MVC Web API:

1) Get the source code of DevDefined.OAuth: https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth - the newest version allows for `OAuthContextBuilder` extensibility.

2) Build the library and reference it in your Web API project.

3) Create a custom context builder to support building a context from `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

using DevDefined.OAuth.Framework;

public class WebApiOAuthContextBuilder : OAuthContextBuilder
{
    public WebApiOAuthContextBuilder()
        : base(UriAdjuster)
    {
    }

    public IOAuthContext FromHttpRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var context = new OAuthContext
            {
                RawUri = this.CleanUri(request.RequestUri), 
                Cookies = this.CollectCookies(request), 
                Headers = ExtractHeaders(request), 
                RequestMethod = request.Method.ToString(), 
                QueryParameters = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                    .ToNameValueCollection(), 
            };

        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            var contentResult = request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            context.RawContent = contentResult.Result;

            try
            {
                // the following line can result in a NullReferenceException
                var contentType = 
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
                context.RawContentType = contentType;

                if (contentType.ToLower()
                    .Contains("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
                {
                    var stringContentResult = request.Content
                        .ReadAsStringAsync();
                    context.FormEncodedParameters = 
                        HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(stringContentResult.Result);
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
            }
        }

        this.ParseAuthorizationHeader(context.Headers, context);

        return context;
    }

    protected static NameValueCollection ExtractHeaders(
        HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var result = new NameValueCollection();

        foreach (var header in request.Headers)
        {
            var values = header.Value.ToArray();
            var value = string.Empty;

            if (values.Length > 0)
            {
                value = values[0];
            }

            result.Add(header.Key, value);
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected NameValueCollection CollectCookies(
        HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> values;

        if (!request.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out values))
        {
            return new NameValueCollection();
        }

        var header = values.FirstOrDefault();

        return this.CollectCookiesFromHeaderString(header);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adjust the URI to match the RFC specification (no query string!!).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">
    /// The original URI. 
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The adjusted URI. 
    /// </returns>
    private static Uri UriAdjuster(Uri uri)
    {
        return
            new Uri(
                string.Format(
                    "{0}://{1}{2}{3}", 
                    uri.Scheme, 
                    uri.Host, 
                    uri.IsDefaultPort ?
                        string.Empty :
                        string.Format(":{0}", uri.Port), 
                    uri.AbsolutePath));
    }
}
```

4) Use this tutorial for creating an OAuth provider: http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuthProvider. In the last step (Accessing Protected Resource Example) you can use this code in your `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` attribute:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    // the only change I made is use the custom context builder from step 3:
    OAuthContext context = 
        new WebApiOAuthContextBuilder().FromHttpRequest(actionContext.Request);

    try
    {
        provider.AccessProtectedResourceRequest(context);

        // do nothing here
    }
    catch (OAuthException authEx)
    {
        // the OAuthException's Report property is of the type "OAuthProblemReport", it's ToString()
        // implementation is overloaded to return a problem report string as per
        // the error reporting OAuth extension: http://wiki.oauth.net/ProblemReporting
        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
               RequestMessage = request, ReasonPhrase = authEx.Report.ToString()
            };
    }
}
```

I have implemented my own provider so I haven't tested the above code (except of course the  `WebApiOAuthContextBuilder` which I'm using in my provider) but it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look at this, though for now I've rolled my own HMAC-based solution.

Comment: @CraigShearer - hi, you say you've rolled your own.. just had a few questions if you don't mind sharing.  I'm in a similar position, where i have a relatively small MVC Web API. The API controllers sit alongside other controller/actions which are under forms auth. Implementing OAuth seems an overkill when I already have a membership provider i could use and I only need to secure a handful of operations. I really want an auth action that returns an encrypted token - then used the token in subsequent calls? any info welcome before I commit to implementing an existing auth solution. thanks!

Comment: @Maksymilian Majer - Any chance you can share how you've implemented the provider in more detail? I'm having some problems sending responses back to the client.

Answer (score 22):

Web API introduced an Attribute `[Authorize]` to provide security. This can be set globally (global.asx)

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Or per controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController{
...
```

Of course your type of authentication may vary and you may want to perform your own authentication, when this occurs you may find useful inheriting from Authorizate Attribute and extending it to meet your requirements:

```
public class DemoAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (Authorize(actionContext))
        {
            return;
        }
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var challengeMessage = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        challengeMessage.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
        throw new HttpResponseException(challengeMessage);
    }

    private bool Authorize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var someCode = (from h in actionContext.Request.Headers where h.Key == "demo" select h.Value.First()).FirstOrDefault();
            return someCode == "myCode";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
[DemoAuthorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController{
```

Here is a link on other custom implemenation for WebApi Authorizations:

http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-membership-provider/

Comment: Thanks for the example @Dalorzo, but I have some issues. I looked at the attached link, but following that instructions doesn't quite work.  I also found needed info missing.  Firstly, when I create the new project, is it right to choose Individual User Accounts for authentication?  Or do I leave it at no authentication.  I'm also not getting the mentioned 302 error, but am getting a 401 error. Lastly, how do I pass the needed info from my view to the controller?  What must my ajax call look like? Btw, I'm using forms authentication for my MVC views. Is that a problem?

Comment: It is working fantastically. Just nice to learn and start working on our own access tokens.

Comment: One small comment - be careful with `AuthorizeAttribute`, as there are two different classes with same name, in different namespaces: 


1. System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute -> for MVC controllers


2. System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute - > for WebApi.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to secure your API in a server to server fashion (no redirection to website for 2 legged authentication). You can look at OAuth2 Client Credentials Grant protocol.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

I have developed a library that can help you easily add this kind of support to your WebAPI. You can install it as a NuGet package:

https://nuget.org/packages/OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrant/1.0.0.0

The library targets .NET Framework 4.5.

Once you add the package to your project, it will create a readme file in the root of your project. You can look at that readme file to see how to configure/use this package.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you sharing/providing source code for this framework as open source?

Comment: JFR: First Link is Broken and NuGet package was never updated

Answer (score 4):

in continuation to @ Cuong Le's answer , my approach to prevent replay attack would be

// Encrypt the Unix Time at Client side using the shared private key(or user's password)

// Send it as part of request header to server(WEB API)

// Decrypt the Unix Time at Server(WEB API) using the shared private key(or user's password)

// Check the time difference between the Client's Unix Time and Server's Unix Time, should not be greater than x sec

// if User ID/Hash Password are correct and the decrypted UnixTime is within x sec of server time then it is a valid request