# Web API creating API keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, api-key

I'm interested in creating API keys for web.api and allowing clients to communicate with API using the API keys rather than authorization web.api provides.

I want multiple clients to be able to communicate with the web.api. instead of creating username and password, can I use an api key, and allow clients to communicate with client.

Is there such built-in functionality?

if one wants to implement it, how would you go around it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You are able to achieve by using [HMAC Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). Basically, there might be a database table called **ApiKey (apiKey, secretKey)**. Each client has each Apikey and secret Key:

1. ApiKey is like a public key and will be sent over HTTP (similar with username).
2. Secret Key is not sent over HTTP, use this secret key to do hmac some information and send hashed output to the server. From server side, based on the public key, you can get the relevent secret key and hash information to compare with hash output.

I have posted the detailed answer at: [How to secure an ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775594/how-to-secure-an-aspnet-mvc-web-api/11782361#11782361)

You can change Username by ApiKey and Hashed Password by secret key on my answer to map with your idea.

Comment: So you will require the client to build the Hash on every API request? What is the overhead involved here?

Comment: I think so, that's the way which HMAC works, please could you elaborate your questions?

Comment: If you will call `ComputeHash(string hashedPassword, string message)` on every method the client calls, how much time does that add to each call? How long does `ComputeHash` take to complete on average?

Comment: has just calculated, around 2600 - 3000 ticks

Comment: Thats nothing, less than a millisecond. So almost no overhead at all, very nice.

Comment: Thanks, we actually applied this approach for our product

Comment: @CuongLe "*ApiKey is like a public key and will be sent over HTTP...Secret Key is not sent over HTTP, use this secret key to do hmac some information and send hashed output to server*" - How do you intend to hash using the secret key if it is never sent over the wire to the client?

Comment: @James: Secret Key is not sent over each HTTP Request every time, but actually client knows secret key, like you sent an email to client to inform the secret key for them.

Comment: So in your scenario "clients" are actually the developers, not users?

Comment: @CuongLe "user cannot user api" - depends on what you mean by that. They don't write code to interact with the API, no. However, they are the end users and essentially they will be the ones "using" the API (albeit behind the scenes). Your approach works if you have "developers" writing client apps, however, what if you didn't open it up to 3rd parties? If I had an API and I wanted to write an app which allowed my users to communicate with it I would have to generate a secret key **per user** and send it over the wire to the device to then secure subsequence requests.

Comment: Just for the record, I am not disagreeing with your answer as for this particular question it is the right way to go. What I am trying to establish is whether or not it could be tweaked in a way where the secret key is generated on a per user basis.

Comment: @James: yes, if you want to use hmac authentication per user, you could create secret key for per user like password.

Comment: @CuongLe I guess this takes us back to the original problem - the secret key would have to be sent across the wire. Using SSL would solve this problem though.

Comment: @James: Yes, agree, if you can use basic authentication for per user over SSL, would be better. You also can send email to inform secret key for each user, why not?

Comment: "*you can also send email to inform secret key for each user, why not?*" - I think this just complicates things, I would prefer if all that stuff happens behind the scenes

Comment: Getting a key to the user has always been a struggle. You could use a 2 step process: have a hashed + salted password sent (along with the salt) over ssl to the service, and have the service send back the associated key. Future transactions use the (hashed + salted) key instead of the password. You could use the password to reset the token as well this way.

Comment: Is this the same approach that google uses for its API's like the js google maps api?