# But Seriously.... Example of ASP.NET WebAPI implementation including OAuth

Tags: web-services, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I'm really not interested in WCF samples. The DotNetOpenAuth implementations that I found are also [incomplete](https://github.com/DavidChristiansen/DotNetOpenAuth.WebAPI.40) or [assume WCF](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/master/samples). I've found [Thinkitecture.IdentityServer.45](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.45) which is anything but lightweight and isn't really appropriate for building into my new WebAPI project. I even found the [Oauth2DotNet](http://nuget.org/packages/OAuth2DotNet) project that has almost no real information.

Microsoft has posted a [few](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth) Oauth/OpenID related projects, but I can't even find proper documentation for these either.

My project: Create a new site to provide "REST-style" API services for authorized mobile applications using .NET 4.5 and ASP.NET WebAPI. Since these applications don't necessarily have to act on behalf of a user, we believe that "2-legged" Oauth will be acceptable because we would like the ability to shut down and deny access to our API if a specific application gets out of hand.

Out of all of this, I've spent a week trying to get a basic implementation working, but haven't even been able to identify the various token types and what makes up the tokens themselves. This really shouldn't be so difficult and I find the lack of basic information on the topics involved quite frustrating. Yes, the specs are posted, but nowhere are they distilled and ready for implementation.

I'd like the ideal solution to extend to integrate properly with the WepAPI's Authenticate attribute, probably as an ActionFilter/AuthorizationFilter so I can identify and authenticate the remote application before attempting to authorize access to one or more of my elegant REST-ful API methods.

Where's the "getting started"?

Comment: Does this help http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

Answer (score 8):

Basically, [HMAC authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) is enough to solve your problem, check out in here:

[How to secure an ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775594/how-to-secure-an-aspnet-mvc-web-api/11782361#11782361)

And:

[Web API creating API keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830338/mvc-4-web-api-creating-api-keys/11831391#11831391)

Comment: It was the perfect answer at the time, but I've still been unable to implement oauth on my WebAPI. I'd like to reopen this question for better answers. I realize that HMAC authentication may be good enough, but this answer does not contain a real solution, just a line of research.