# ASP.NET WEB API Authorization or User based Licensing

Tags: authorization, wcf-data-services, asp.net-web-api2

Have done a lot of search and reading over the WEB but could not come to any conclusion yet.

We are planning to develop a list of API's (planning to use ASP.NET WEB API). One of the business goals is to package the API and selling/licensing the Packages/API to end users.

Some thoughts that came to consideration:

Using Authorisation Filters to do check against database, if the user requesting the API has access to it or not. Not very sure of the implementation details yet even on this approach.

Are there any better suggestions or ideas or any open source libraries that we can go with?

What are the possible recommendation or best practices to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following links. Hopefully, they help.

[Web API creating API keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830338/web-api-creating-api-keys)

[How to secure an ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775594/how-to-secure-an-asp-net-web-api/11782361#11782361)