# Encode/Decode an id using a salt

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

I have an `api` that I want allow users to send an `id` to, but I don't want the id to be visible over a network. I decided that I will then generate a `secret` for the user which will be used as a salt to hash the `id` they send. They will then take that `id` and `secret` to connect to my `api`.

The server is written with `node.js`, and the client will be written in `c#`, so I need a way so that both languages can encode/decode if they know the `secret`.

So...

- `C#` will encode the `id`
- `Node.js` will decode the `id`

I have never create an salt like this before, so what method(s) can I use to do this? I think eventually I will be using more just `C#` to encode the `id`, so methods for other languages would be awesome too!

Comment: Wouldn't TLS be sufficient?

Comment: Maybe.. I've never heard of it

Comment: You might know it as SSL/HTTPS

Comment: Cant the client still see the data that is going through?

Comment: You said "visible over a network". Exactly what or who are you trying to hide the value from?

Comment: I want to hide it from someone on the network and the user using the application. The application will be either a mobile app or a desktop app.

Comment: What does the id reference? A user? A record in the system?

Comment: You should assume that (unless you're in _total_ control of the machine the client application is running on), that they can see everything on it anyway.

Comment: `id` refers to a primary key usually the registered application id. So if you see the application Id on the network you could create an app and use that id to write to that application instead of your own application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide information from prying eyes, use TLS (as suggested in the comments).
Also from the comments, it looks like what you want is not to hide the ID but a way to sign messages so you can make sure the messages you receive are legal messages from your application. In this case, each message you receive will come with a hash, that hash is computed from the message and the secret key. Then your server will try to compute the same hash from the received message and the stored secret key and then compare it to the received hash. A salt has a different use.
(this was intended as a comment but didn't fit)

See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code
- [Web API creating API keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830338/web-api-creating-api-keys)
- [How to secure an ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775594/how-to-secure-an-asp-net-web-api/11782361#11782361)

Comment: This sound like a legit way to do it, basically I would send a token along with the request that my server could build.

Comment: @TheBoogieMan if that's what you want its called HMAC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code