# ASP.NET Web API with x509 security certificate

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api, x509certificate

I'm going to use [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot)
 for my asp.net web api authentication and I'm supposed to implement [X509 Certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509).

There is an article in msdn about [How to: Secure a Service with an X.509 Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788968.aspx), which is for WCF services that uses `ServiceHost` class. So the question is how to achieve this in asp.net web api services? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

There are some "prerequisites" to work with SSL that is:

- [Setting up IIS to work with the SSL](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis)

You may also want to take  a look at:

- [Custom Authentication Methods with Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21634723/1959948)

Here is a full Article on:

- [How to secure web api using SSL Certificate](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api):

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on stack overflow due to the risk of the referenced article being altered, path changed, or removed by the target site. Extracting the relevant information into the question and linking to the site as a backing resource is preferred.