# Authentication best practice in ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I just got lost with trying to find a suitable way to implement authentication in my MVC project.
I tried to search some good solution from the google. The problem is I don't know how to implement authentication to both MVC and WebAPI. But I found actually there are too many ways of implement authentication in asp.net mvc . Some traditional ways like Windows Authentication, FormAuthentication, even we can use the Basic Authentication. And MVC itself also provide some Authentication Attribute or filter to provide security mechanism. and some others 3rd party authentication framework like OAuth also can do this part of work for us.

So I really don't know what is the best way to implement authentication in my project (Asp.net MVC + Web Api).

Some helpful link so far I just found below:

[How to secure an ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775594/how-to-secure-an-asp-net-web-api)

http://jameschambers.com/2013/11/working-with-iauthenticationfilter-in-the-mvc-5-framework/

Comment: http://asp.net/identity

Comment: @BrendanGreen Thanks! +1

Comment: You could take a look at this example of a onion architecture that encapsulates the Identity managers in a separate project. This way you can use the same managers in both Web API and MVC projects. http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-sample-of-onion-architecture-with-asp-net-identity

Comment: @rcompanhoni ok . Thanks!+1