# How to make a custom Authorize attribute in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

In MVC 4 we can override some methods of `AuthorizeAttribute` class to implemenrt custom Authorize attribute.

For an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21634723/6120338

```
public class DemoAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (Authorize(actionContext))
        {
            return;
        }
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var challengeMessage = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        challengeMessage.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
        throw new HttpResponseException(challengeMessage);
    }

    private bool Authorize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var someCode = (from h in actionContext.Request.Headers where h.Key == "demo" select h.Value.First()).FirstOrDefault();
            return someCode == "myCode";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and controller will be

```
[DemoAuthorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController{
```

This is in MVC4. But how to do the same in ASP.NET CORE? 

There is no `OnAuthorization` , `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`, `Authorize` overriding method in `AuthorizeAttribute` class.

Comment: You are not supposed to override the Authorize Attribute. You are supposed to use the policy based authentication. See the post from blowdart (person at ASP.NET Core team responsible for the ASP.NET Core Security)

Comment: Thanks, It is likely same. But I need to filter Request Header .