# WebApi and Controller Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've currently got an MVC4 site running with custom user authentication (we eventually set  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie) and everything works fine.

I want to move from the current setup and use a new Web API to serve the data in a REST format

my question is - using a Web API what is the best way to check if a user is logged in?
 say we want to just expose the Web API to another device, how could I control a user being authorized to use the API?

any help would be great!

cheers
ste.

Comment: This is similar to a question raised here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531475/net-mvc-4-webapi-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this sample, should be exactly what you need:

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/23/mixing-mvc-forms-authentication-and-web-api-basic-authentication/