# Jquery Grid - Serial Port Communication

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, serial-port, struts2-jquery-grid

I have a serial Port program which is executing properly with Hardware and it's able to get the data from my hardware. But,Is it possible to load that data in Jquery Grid? If so ,pls refer me some useful links to work on my task! Thank You in advance.

Quick responses Would be grateful.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should understand that web browser can't access the hardware like serial port directly. So to display the data from serial port in jqGrid you have to divide your application in two parts: the first one will be an fat client application which access the serial port and the second part is web site which provide the data for HTML page with jqGrid. You can combine the application which access serial port and the web site in one web application.

I'm not a [struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/) developer. So I would use on your place Windows Service with [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) (see [here](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-web-api) and here too). The design of the application very easy. You can create Windows Service application. Then you creates [self hosting WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api) inside of `OnStart` callback. You can use windows authentication (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864370/315935)) and set `Routes.MapHttpRoute` to register all URLs which can be used to access the windows service. For example you can register two URLs: one which returns HTML page with JavaScript code which creates jqGrid and another URL to the controller which provide the data for Ajax requests. Because your application will be a Windows Service it can access hardware like serial port (with respect of [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example). As Self-Host WebAPI application your application don't need IIS be installed on the computer. In general you can make the application first as any simple windows application (like console application) instead of creating windows service. All will work in the same way. You could just need to include the [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) which allows to start application under administrative rights.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I am sorry that I am not aware of .Net,I am working on jsp,java and as u said, I have divided my application into two parts, one which  gets the output from serial port (Java main Method), and the other is a jsp page with jqgrid.

Comment: I need solution to set that output what i m getting from the serial port program to a GUI component such as Jqgrid or HTML TableCell.

Comment: @Mathu: Sorry, but I can't provide you any references to JSP, Java etc solutions because I don't use the technology myself. Probably [JAX-RS 2.0](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) is something what you can consider to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg,as u said let me look into RESTFul Services API.