# Authenticate HTTP .NET client against Self Host Web API Windows Service

Tags: asp.net, .net, self-host-webapi

I found great article about client/server implementation via **Self Host Web API** 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api

And I am wondering about the correct authentication method for this model (**Self Host Web API** ).

Have I use a **bearer token authentication**? Is there any other method?

Or for example http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

I have following working requirements:

> 1. C# http client must connect to Self Host Web API Windows Service and send files.
> 2. The connection must be secure 100%.

So  how to protect WebAPI, any clue?

Comment: So like 80% secure is not an option?

Comment: @CodeCaster hahahaa Hey man! I am glad to see u again. IT IS :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked this answer?

[ASP.NET Web API Self-Host with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571445/asp-net-web-api-self-host-with-windows-authentication)

Looks like is working quite well with Windows Authentication.

BTW, Bearer it's probably more flexible, but it depends on your needs.

BTW(2): HTTPS is a must if you want to achive an high level of security, but 100% looks veeery high :)